# git set files to assume-unchanged

Tags: git, git-assume-unchanged

Git is always setting to `assume-unchanged` all the files from two of my repository. After each `commit`, `checkout`, `pull`, and so on, it set `assume-unchanged` on the modified files. I have to execute `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged my_file` to `commit` and `push` my modifications.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Why would git auto set `assume-unchanged`? What git app are you using? Could be some weird setting from your git app?

Comment: Repos are on my own gitlab server, and I have sourcetree and git bash on windows